# Speed up loading big database

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

In a Microsoft Access database, I've got around 150'000 entries that are temperature measurement values from a sensor.

I want to visualize them in a .NET chart control in C#.

Because it would be too slow to load all the values into the chart and it would be far too exact as that one could see every data point, I've tried to load all values into a Tuple and then calculate how many data points I have to skip to get max. 2'000 data points in the chart.

However it doesn't run that fast and I was wondering if anyone had an idea how I could change the sql command itself or the loading routine.

I know FastLine chart type, but I'd still like to provide the functions of the Line type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can sort by time, and then select rows where their row number MOD (150000/2000) == 0 (so we pick every 75th row in this case). Shouldn't be too intensive. Make sure you have proper indexes set up (especially for the columns you sort by)

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot, but before loading, I don't know how many entries there are... Any other solution?

Comment: You can ask database how many records the table has.

Comment: Just do a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable`, if it has  a primary key, that is very fast.